# many consumers to manu queues. One consumer to multiple queues in the RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

Good afternoon!

What is the best way to implement the next:

I publish messages about employees. I want that consumer process messages about several employees. For example - I send messages about employees 1,2,3,4,5. I want to process messages in the next way: Consumer 1 - receives messages about employees 1,3,5; Consumer 2 - receives messages about employees 2,4,5

If I create a certain queue for each employee, how can I subscribe the consumer for greater then one queue?
I can send messages in the one queue with the different routing keys (EmployeeID). In this way - how can I filter messages in this queue by the multiple routing keys for different consumers?

Comment: Your logic of choosing which messages to process is unclear, e.g. message 5 goes to both consumers. Where are these routing rules declared?

Comment: The logic is clear. I want the first consumer to receive messages about employees 1,3,5; the second consumer - about employees 2,4,5. And looking for the best solution for this

Comment: And I am trying to find a way to implement this. I would create two queues - one for employees 1,3,5, the second - for workers 2,4,5. But what to set in such a case as a queue identifier, or a routing key. After all, I don’t know in advance how to group workers in turns

Comment: The second way, I think - sends messages about all employees into one queue, where the routing key is the employee Id. But how can I filter this queue by multiple routing keys?

Comment: The third way - create a separate queue for each employee. But how can I subscribe the ONE consumer to work with multiple queues? In the end, I don’t know in advance what kind of employees the consumer will subscribe to.

Comment: I found the solution. I created exchange and the separate queues with the specific binding

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I created exchange and the separate queues with the specific binding